# placing image logo and brand name nicely on the navbar React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

I'm trying to place my logo nicely on the top left corner of the navbar. However, when I do that the brand name gets placed in a weird position.

[image: justify-content: center || space-around || space-evenly;]

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how I could place the logo and brand nicely on the navbar.

This is the HTML:

```
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div className="nav-wrapper">
      <Link
        to={this.props.auth ? "/dashboard" : "/"}
        className="left brand-logo"
      >
        <img src={Logo} alt="logo" className="photo" />
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
      </Link>
      <ul className="right">{this.renderContent()}</ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And this is the css:

```
#navbar {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.photo {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```

I am currently using materialize CSS for the navbar.

Comment: Could you share via codesandbox . It takes time to install dependencies and debug from here

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Sure, here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-shape-60qez?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Great Let me debug it for you :) .

Comment: Done ! Ttry the answer :)

Comment: See how fast one can debug, when code is there on codesandbox. Issue is resolved now. I have shared my updated CodesandBox link also. Do Vote and Accept the answer dear :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css line and you are good to go.

```
.brand-logo {
  display: inline-flex !important;
}
```

CodesandBox:
[Logo Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/logoissue-imy6e)

Comment: thank you for debugging. However, i cannot load the link. Could you try posting a new link? Thanks!

Comment: Sure... Mean while do try with the above CSS code. Add it at the end of your CSS file :)

Comment: where is the brand-logo in terms of the HTML?

Comment: Have updated the link as well. Brand Logo is coming from Link Component, coming from materialize I guess which get converted to <a> tag and is set to that.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much

Comment: Joseezy, Wait. I found something . In your codesandbox you have used <a> Tags directly.Check line number 24 and 30. Are you allowed to do so. I just found this.

Comment: I changed it to a tags from link tags to adjust to sandbox. I have the actual code on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: Though it is a small thing! I mean are you linking to some other resource or a component within the app? :)

Comment: Cool  very nice then !!! If it workd fine. That makes me feel so happy when I help someone ... Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `nav-wrapper` as `display:"flex"` and use `align-items:"center".`
Then it should work fine.

Do let me know if this was something you were looking for.

If not we can try few more things.

```css
#Nav_Bar {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#Nav_Bar>div {
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
  max-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="Nav_Bar">
    <div id="Logo_Wrapper">
      <a href="https:google.com">
        <img src="./Logo.JPG" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Logo</h2>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-box

```
  #navbar{
   display:flex;
   align-items:flex-start;
   justify-content:center || space-around || space-evenly;
   }
```

This should do it, flex-box makes it effortless to create navbars.
Add margin padding where you see fit.